# add 2 history in 1 table codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this `HTML` table which displays history and I display the data like this

**My controller:**

```php
$data['cashoutrequest'] = $this->investor->getCashoutRequest($this->session->userdata('refcode'));
$data['investHistory'] = $this->investor->account_history($this->session->userdata('refcode'));
```

**My view:**

```php
<?php if($cashoutrequest != null) {?>
                    <?php $i=1;foreach($cashoutrequest as $rec): ?>
                    <?php foreach($investHistory as $rec2): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rec['referal_code']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rec['activity']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rec['description']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rec['date']; ?></td>
                        <?php if($rec['status'] == 0) { echo "<td>pending</td>"; } else { echo "<td>confirmed</td>"; } ?>

                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                    <?php } ?>
```

I want also to display some data on the investing history but it's not working. It displays nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you're outputting the investHistory somewhere? I don't see you using `$rec2` anywhere in that code

Comment: @kerbholz when I do that it doesn't make any output

Comment: you might be able to join cashoutrequest and investhistory with a SQL query and avoid the double loop, but for that we'd need to know your data structure. In your current approach, you need to establish some conditional relation between rec2 and rec and when met create the desired output.

Comment: Show `print_r()` of both `$cashoutrequest` and `$investHistory`, or part of them at least, either it would be very hard to help you.